# OAuth PLAINTEXT signature method?

Tags: oauth, spring-security, jersey

all is in the title. I want to use PLAINTEXT as signature-method for my OAuth implementation. Any suggestion?

Comment: what kind of suggestion? about any API or..?

Comment: A suggestion on how i can tell OAuth to use PLAINTEXT signature method instead of HMAC-SHA1

Answer (score 1):

i have read about it when i was working on OAuth using yahoo and here is a sample request using plaintext for yahoo

```
https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth/v2/get_token?oauth_consumer_key=key
  &oauth_signature_method=PLAINTEXT
  &oauth_version=1.0
  &oauth_verifier=svmhhd
  &oauth_token=gugucz&oauth_timestamp=1228169662
  &oauth_nonce=8B9SpF
  &oauth_signature=5f78507cf0acc38890cf5aa697210822e90c8b1c%261fa61b464613d0d32de80089fe099caf34c9dac5
```

here are more details for Yahoo
[Yahoo OAuth using PlainText](http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-accesstoken.html)

if i remember correctly Google does not support this version

with which OAuth service you want to use this PLAINTEXT?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Jersey OAuth modules you can simply call signatureMethod("PLAINTEXT") on the OAuthParameters instance you are using. But you did not indicate what OAuth libraries you are using, only from tags I am guessing you are using Jersey and you don't say if this is for the server or the client side. So, if you want to get help, it may be worth the time to make the question a bit more specific.